# Finding what NS is used for a subdomain?

Tags: dns, nameservers, dig

Two questions from a dns newb:

1. Is it possible for a subdomain to use a different set of nameservers than its parent domain? 
   Eg: abc.ca uses ns.whatever.com and ns2.whatever.com, while sub.abc.ca uses ns.anything.com and ns2.anything.com
2. If this is possible, what is the command to look this up? Would something as simple as this work?

> ```
> dig ns sub.abc.ca
> ```

Comment: correct syntax should be: dig sub.abc.ca NS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be on the safe side you should *directly* ask the authoritative servers at the parent domain about any `NS` records for the sub-domain.

```
% dig +norec @parent sub.example.com. ns
```

This ensures you'll get the current answer straight from the horses mouth, rather than whatever happens to be in your local recursive resolver's cache.

Comment: I get this message: `dig: couldn't get address for 'parent': not found`

Comment: @Flimm `parent` needs to be replaced with the actual hostname of a name server for the parent zone.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you're spot on. Other options include: `host -t NS sub.abc.ca`